# Change function arguments inside function

Tags: php

HTML form sends empty values as empty strings. I want them to be null:

```
function dummy($arg1, $arg2, ... $argN)
{
   if(!$arg1) $arg1 = null;
   if(!$arg2) $arg2 = null;
   ... 
   if(!$argN) $argN = null

}
```

This is very ugly. I want something like:

```
function dummy($arg1, $arg2, ... $argN)
{
   nullEmptyArguments();
   var_dump($arg1); //null
}
```

Comment: Why set the arguments to null? If they are only set to null when they evaluate to false, then simply checking the condition (!$arg1) is equivalent to checking, setting to null, and later checking for null.

Comment: This is not a problem you typically need a solution for. Sounds like you should structure your code inside your function differently. It really hardly makes sense to do what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function [`get_defined_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) to get all defined variables, and loop over them and re-set them:

```
function dummy($arg1, $arg2, $argN)
{
    foreach (get_defined_vars() as $k => $v) $$k = $v ?: null;
    // your logic
}

dummy(1, '0', ''); # $arg2 & $argN will be set to NULL
```

Comment: good point from the $$, because with $v doesn't work. but what about the &$ ?

Comment: @BubuDaba: I don't understand what doesn't work with `$v`? And what do you mean by `&$`? What would you like to pass by reference?

Comment: Oh I meant if `dummy($a,$b,$c)`, to change the variables

Comment: If you would use `function dummy(&$arg1, &$arg2, &$argN)` then your input must be variables like you shown, and not values, like in my answer, because you would get `Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference`.